# View binded :key values in Vue3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

```
<li v-for="(size, index) in sizes" :key="index">{{ size }}</li>
```

I'm new to VueJS and I'm playing around with Vue Directives. I wanna know where to get the list of `:key` values in the console log or developer tools. For now, I'm setting it to `id` attribute and reading it. Appreciate any kind of help

Comment: you can set the `:key` to `index`. I hope I understand as this isn't a very clear question.

Comment: There is an extension named vuejs devtools for chrome. You can see the component state without needing to dump it to the console.

Comment: @Eldar, If I want to dump the key value to console, how do I do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just playing around with it and want to be able to log it to console, you could add a log function to your methods

```js
  methods:{
    log(..args){
        console.log(...args)
    }
  }
```

then you can use the log function anywhere and pass it the same value

```html
<li v-for="(size, index) in sizes" :key="index">{{ size }}{{log(index)}}</li>
```

...but that only works if you can pass the same value to both

#### Example:

```js
Vue.createApp({
  data: () => ({
    items: ['a', 'b', 'c']
  }),
  methods: {
    log(...args) {
      console.log(...args)
    },
  },
}).mount("#app");
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.2.0/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <li v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">{{ item }}{{log(index)}}</li>
</div>
```

Comment: Understood. Thank you. Why does our custom method call `{{log(index)}}` work and JS logging `{{console.log(index)}}` doesn't work ?

Comment: because the vue template uses a different context. Its kind-of like calling something from within the script using `this`. If you try calling `this.console.log` you'll see an error there too